# php syntax with visual paradigm

Tags: php, visual-paradigm

I'm getting an error on my PHP code when I try to reverse-egineer PHP code.
This line in particular

```
$adapter  = new \Geocoder\HttpAdapter\CurlHttpAdapter();
```

It's not liking the backslash. How can I fix this, is there better way in PHP to write this perhaps?

```
Reason :
Error occured when analysis: /home/vincent/dnseq/geo.php. Lexical error at line 189, column 29.  Encountered: "\\" (92), after : ""
```

Comment: Are you running PHP 5.4? Or was it 5.3 that supports namespaces? I'm not sure, check it! :D

Comment: yes I'm on PHP 5.4, the php runs fine but the reverse engineering feature of VP fails

Answer (score 1):

That code is perfectly valid in PHP 5.3 and 5.4

Look like you need to update Visual Paradigm, or 5.3 is not supported.

http://forums.visual-paradigm.com/posts/list/288199.html

Comment: The app tells me the error is at character 29 which is basically right at the start of the first \ after new